# Blocking Reddit on android

Tags: browser, hosts

I have a habit of using reddit app and I want to kick out this habit. I have tried the following ways to block reddit.

1. Blacklisted this website on a blocker and now cannot access it in any browser. ( BlockerX).
2. Tried blocking many other apps like Boost, Reddit for android, Sync which provide access to reddit.

Now, the issue is that there are so many other apps available on Play Store to provide access to reddit. It is ineffective and inefficient to block every Reddit app available on Play store.

So, Is there any other way to totally block access to reddit and it's third party apps ?

May be something technical like editing hosts file or build.prop file.

Comment: If an app works with reddit then it most likely uses their API which is also located on the www.reddit.com server. Hence blocking this server should also prevent other apps from contacting reddit. Can you explain why you want such a block? If you don't like reddit simply not using reddit and ignoring reddit content when to see it should be enough in my opinion.

Comment: @Robert..It's like an addiction that's why I want some mechanical stop from using this website. How can I block a server if my phone is not rooted?

Comment: VPN based ad blockers like Blokada and AdGuard can block complete servers by redirecting their traffic to localhost (-> no connection + no data). The work purely on the device itself.

Comment: @Robert..can we also do it by editing hosts file? I don't have a rooted phone. Vpn based softwares consume excessive battery.

Comment: Editing hosts file requires rooted device. And VPN is only battery excessive if the VPN does a lot transformations and/or the endpoint is not on your device. Just thy out Blokada (I prefer v4 instead of v5).